# Selecet XML Nodes by similar names in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a `xml`File which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ImageConfig>
  <Image Name="">
    <Include-Software></Include-Software>
    <RoboCopy></RoboCopy>
    <Image-Path></Image-Path>
    <Software0>xyz</Software0>
    <Software1>abc</Software1>
    <Software2>def</Software2>
    <Software3>ghf</Software3>
    <Software4>wew</Software4>
    <Software5>hjf</Software5>
  </Image>
</ImageConfig>
```

I want select all nodes with the with the Name `Software*` to delete the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the file using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet and cast the result to `xml`. Then filter all children of `ImageConfig.Image` where the name match `Software\d+` using the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet and remove the value. Finally, write the xml back using the `Save` method:

```
$xmlFilePath = 'your_path_here.xml'

[xml]$xml  = Get-Content $xmlFilePath
$xml.ImageConfig.Image.ChildNodes | Where-Object Name -Match 'Software\d+' | ForEach-Object {
    $_.'#text' = ''
}

$xml.Save($xmlFilePath)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. That was what i was looking for. I tried with Where-Object but with "

Comment: Your welcome. Please consider to accept the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work