# Replacting XML node text using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am having my XML document as follows

```
  <Batch>
  <Alter>
    <ObjectDefinition>
      <DataSources>
        <DataSource>
          <ConnectionString>Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=ABC;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog =TesDB1</ConnectionString>
          <ConnectionString>Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=XYZ;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog =TesDB1</ConnectionString>
        </DataSource>
      </DataSources>
    </ObjectDefinition>
  </Alter>
</Batch>
```

I would like to replace the entire connection-string nodes as follows

`$ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=$DataSource;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog =$Database"`

Here is what I tried but this is replacing only one node content

```
$XMLA = "D:\employee.xml"
$SqlDataBase = [xml](Get-Content $XMLA)
$data = $SqlDataBase.SelectNodes("Batch/Alter/ObjectDefinition/DataSources/DataSource/ConnectionString")
#$data
$DataSource = "localhost"
foreach($xn in $data)
{

   $DataBase = $xn.'#text'.Split(";").Split("=")
   $DataBase[$DataBase.Length - 1]
   $DataBase = $DataBase[$DataBase.Length - 1]

   $ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=$DataSource;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog =$Database"

   $SqlDataBase.SelectSingleNode("Batch/Alter/ObjectDefinition/DataSources/DataSource/ConnectionString").InnerText = "$ConnectionString";
}
$SqlDataBase.Save($XMLA)
```

So any better way to replace multiple nodes please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best way where I have taken the source from here

[Selecet XML Nodes by similar names in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992689/selecet-xml-nodes-by-similar-names-in-powershell)

```
$XMLA = "D:\employee.xml"
$SqlDataBase = [xml](Get-Content $XMLA)
$data = $SqlDataBase.SelectNodes("Batch/Alter/ObjectDefinition/DataSources/DataSource/ConnectionString")
#$data
$DataSource = "localhost"

$SqlDataBase.Batch.Alter.ObjectDefinition.DataSources.DataSource.ChildNodes | Where-Object Name -Match 'ConnectionString' | ForEach-Object {

    $DataBase = $_.'#text'.Split(";").Split("=")
    $DataBase = $DataBase[$DataBase.Length - 1]

    $ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=$DataSource;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog =$Database"

    $_.'#text' = "$ConnectionString"
}

$SqlDataBase.Save($XMLA)
```